# htaccess redirect How to redirect subfolder to subdomain and subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I moved a portion of the site to a subdomain. All answers I find here are without keeping the folder structure in mind.

So

```
http://mywebsite.com/projects
```

Has become

```
http://topic.mywebsite.com/projects
```

So what I have now is:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/projects/(.*)$ http://topic.mywebsite.com/projects/$1
```

But this creates an infinite loop.
So I tried

```
RedirectMatch 301 http://mywebsite.com/projects/(.*)$ http://topic.mywebsite.com/projects/$1
```

So it does not get into a loop on the subdomain, but this does not work at all.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mod_rewrite` and check that it only runs for the main site.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =mywebsite.com
RewriteRule ^projects/(.*)$ http://topic.mywebsite.com/projects/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for saving the day.